# What does "linear in the first component" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

What does linear in the first component mean in general?
I have seen some mathematical tasks where I have given a map and then I have to prove that is linear in the first component. 
I mean I know how to prove linearity, but I don't understand what is meant by "the first component"?

Comment: Can you give a particular example where the expression is used?

Comment: I think this has something to do with proving that the submap of the 1st principal component is linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a map $f:D^n \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^m$ say, where $D$ is the domain of $f$, the *components* of the map are the $n$ elements that make up the domain.  For example, $$f:{\mathbb R}^3 \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2 \mbox{ given by } f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2, z/2)$$
has three components, $x,y$ and $z$.

To show that $f$ is linear in the first component, we must show that $f(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2, \ldots) = \alpha f(x_1, \ldots ) + \beta f(x_2, \ldots)$, i.e. that if we ignore everything other than the first component (here $x$) then we get a linear result.  Consider our example again:
$$ f(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2, y, z) = ((\alpha x_1 +\beta x_2)^2 +y^2, z/2) $$
and since $(\alpha x_1 +\beta x_2)^2 = \alpha ^2 x_1^2 + 2\alpha \beta x_1 x_2 + \beta ^2 x_2^2$ we see that $f$ is definitely not going to be linear in the first component.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good example!

Comment: Sorry, slight mistake there, $f$ is not linear in $z$ at all; my first example had the range being ${\mathbb R}$ not ${\mathbb R}^2$.  Will edit now.

Comment: Note that if you want an $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ map to be linear in $z$, you must have $f(x,y,0)\equiv (0,0)$

Answer (score 2):

If you have a map with two input variables like this
$f(x_1,x_2)$
then $x_1$ can be referred to as "the first component". Now suppose $x_1$ is taken from a vector space $V$ and $f$ outputs a value in a vector space $W$, so that expressions like ($a,b$ are scalars for $V$)
$$f(ax_1+by_1,x_2)$$
$$af(x_1,x_2)$$
$$f(x_1,x_2)+f(x_2,y_2)$$
are defined. Then such an $f$ is said to be **linear in its first component** if
$$f(ax_1+by_2,x_2)=af(x_1,x_2)+bf(y_1,x_2)$$
is always true ($a,b$ are scalars). You can easily generalize this to multivariable maps. In other words, **linear in its first component** means **if you fix all other variables, what is left is a linear map**.

Scalar product would be the most common example. A fancier one would be the tensor product.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function of more variables, let us say $f(x, y, z)$ , being linear in the first component means $f(x_1 + x_2 , y, z) = f(x_1 , y, z) + f(x_2 ,y, z)$
and $f(ax, y, z) = a f(x, y, z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a function $f : x,\, y \mapsto f(x,\, y)$ between vector spaces. $f$ is linear in the first component if for every fixed $y_0$, the function $x \mapsto f(x,y_0)$ is linear.

In other words, for every $x,\, x',\, y$ and every scalars $\alpha, \, \beta$, one has :
$$f(\alpha x + \beta x', y) = \alpha f(x,y) + \beta f(x',y)$$